# Command not found when I use expo to create a react-native project

Tags: node.js, expo

I try to create a react native project by this command: `expo init firstproject` but it said that: `C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found`. However, I've already install expo-cli and exp and I don't know why this happen :(( (Yesterday this command sill worked). Is there anything I make wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Which node version are you using? I get the same problem, but only with node 16.

Comment: I resolved this problem just add `npx` before this command